# Set up printer to only use A4

Tags: cups

I have one size of paper: A4 - not letter, not legal, not A3, but only one size and that is A4.

It is therefore frustrating again and again to see Linux try to print out on another size, which of course results in wasted time and paper.

Is there a bulletproof way to have CUPS always change the size to A4 before it is sent to the printer - no matter what the job asks for?

It would also be nice if letter and legal was never available to any program - because selecting those sizes would always be a mistake.

Comment: Have you tried editing changing `/etc/papersize` so that it contains `a4`?  i did that years ago (so long that I've forgotten when, probably some time in the '90s) and everything just defaults to `a4` for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `/etc/papersize` to `a4` and all programs<sup>1</sup> will default to using `a4` as the paper size.

e.g. (as a non-root user with `sudo` privileges):

```
echo a4 | sudo tee /etc/papersize
```

or, as root:

```
echo a4 > /etc/papersize
```

<sup>1</sup>or almost all.  There might be a few odd programs with `letter` or `legal` hard-coded.  There's not much you can do about them except replace them with software that isn't broken.  Everything that uses CUPS should be OK.  LibreOffice, and most web browsers and PDF viewers, for example.

Comment: Preliminary tests look great.